# Members specific to the error view in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Trying to find list of standard `$this` members, specific to the ZF2 error handler view such as `display_exceptions` or `exception` with no success. Those names appears only in code samples but not in ZF2 documentation.

Is there a list of `$this` members, available in view/error view or the only way to get it is digging into ZF2 source code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only variables available are the ones assigned to the view model. In the case of the error handler, it's the exception strategies that do this. For general exceptions: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/ExceptionStrategy.php#L121 and for 'route not found' ones specifically: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/RouteNotFoundStrategy.php#L165